# Valores de fórmulas não correspondem

Tags: php, html, microsoft-excel

Estou tentando fazer a fórmula do Excel **VF(valor futuro)** em PHP, porém os valores não estão correspondendo, ou seja, no Excel está um valor para a coluna e no calculo do PHP saem outros valores mas valores quase idênticos, distantes de R$ 1,50 a R$ 3,00.

## index.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-sac">
        <style type="text/css">
          .table-sac thead tr th,
          tbody tr td {
            text-align: center;
          }
        </style>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Mes</th>
            <th>Se for investir</th>
            <th>Juros no finan.</th>
            <th>Amortização</th>
            <th>VT</th>
            <th>Valor futuro</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php require_once('calcs.php'); ?>
          <?php for($i = 0; $i <= $mes; $i++): ?>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <?php echo $i; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo number_format($sac['G'][$i], 2, ',', '.'); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo number_format($sac['H'][$i], 2, ',', '.'); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo number_format($sac['I'][$i], 2, ',', '.'); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo number_format($sac['J'][$i], 2, ',', '.'); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $sac['K']['vf'][$i]; ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php endfor; ?>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- row -->
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

## calcs.php

```
<?php
// F = P. (1+i)° + M.[(1+i)° - 1]/i
function vf($taxa,$n,$pgto,$vlr_presente=0, $iterador)
{
    if($iterador > 0):
        // $first  = bcmul($GLOBALS['ul_vf'],   $taxa);
        // $second = bcadd($GLOBALS['ul_pgto'], $first);
        // $vf     = bcadd($GLOBALS['ul_vf'],   $second);
        // $vf = ($GLOBALS['ul_vf']) + ($GLOBALS['ul_vf'] * $taxa + $GLOBALS['ul_pgto']);
        $first  = bcadd(1, $taxa);
        $second = bcpow($first, $n);
        $third  = bcmul($GLOBALS['ul_vf'], $second); 

        $fourth = bcsub($second, 1);
        $fifth  = bcdiv($fourth, $taxa);
        $sixth  = bcmul($fifth, $GLOBALS['ul_pgto']);

        $seventh = bcadd($third, $sixth);
        $vf = $seventh;

        $GLOBALS['ul_vf']   = $vf;
        $GLOBALS['ul_pgto'] = $pgto;
    else:
        $vf = $vlr_presente;
        $GLOBALS['ul_vf']   = $vf;
        $GLOBALS['ul_pgto'] = $pgto;
    endif;
    return $vf;
}




$vlr_imovel   = 144000; //var_dump($vlr_imovel);
$vlr_aluguel  = 400.00; //var_dump($vlr_imovel);
$vlr_entrada  = 43200.00; //var_dump($vlr_imovel);
$vlr_encargos = 500.00; //var_dump($vlr_imovel);
$mes = 360;

$taxa = (0.54/100);
$se_for_investir  = $vlr_encargos + $vlr_entrada;

for($i = 0; $i <= $mes; $i++):

    $juros_no_finan    = (($vlr_imovel - $vlr_entrada) - ((($vlr_imovel - $vlr_entrada)/$mes)*$i))*0.007;

    $amortizacao      = ($vlr_imovel - $vlr_entrada)/$mes;

    $vlr_total        = $amortizacao + $juros_no_finan;

    //VALOR FUTURO -------------------------
    // Como: FV = PV x ( 1 + i ) ^ n
    $n            = 1; 
    $pgto         = $vlr_total - $vlr_aluguel;
    $vlr_presente = $vlr_entrada + $vlr_encargos;
    $tipo         = 0;
    $one = 0.96;
    $two = 0.42;
    $taxa2        = 0.54/100;

    $vf           = vf($taxa2, $n, $pgto, $vlr_presente, $i);
    //VALOR FUTURO -------------------------


    $sac['G'][] = $se_for_investir;
    $sac['H'][] = $juros_no_finan;
    $sac['I'][] = $amortizacao;
    $sac['J'][] = $vlr_total;


    $sac['K']['pgto'][] = $pgto;
    $sac['K']['vf'][]   = $vf;

endfor;
```

Explicação do código.

1 - Eu faço um loop nos meses, 360 meses ao todo.

2 - No primeiro loop(0) a função `FV` é chamada, `FV` recebe os parametros:
`($taxa, $parcelas, $pagamento, $vlr_presente, $iterador_atual)` Esses parâmetos
são do loop atual.

3 - Na FV(função) temos condicionais que verificam se o `$iterador`(que foi passado pelo parâmetro) é > 1, exemplo:

```
if(iterador > 1):
    //aqui eu faço a formula com as variaveis globais no else abaixo
    //e insiro variaveis globais para ser aproveitadas no proximo loop
else:
    //aqui é o primeiro loop, ou seja a primeira linha do excel(o mês 0)
    //variavel global desse valor passado(será aproveitada no proximo loop)
    //variavel global do pagamento passado(será aproveitada no proximo loop)
endif;
return $valorFuturo;
```

4 - Agora, no Calcs.php temos o valor futuro que será passado para a view;

---

O Erro aqui é que os valores não são idênticos, quase, mas não idênticos. Pensei que poderiam ser os floats, que estavam atrapalhando mas não é.

Coloquei o [arquivo excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsgBPIHK-IqZgTAN1fHnQ8cSH22a) no google drive.

Comment: De novo, coloca um exemplo númerico da sua função. Pegue uma linha que dê diferente e coloque os valores aqui e como é feito a chamada da função para estes valores. Fica muito confuso entender tanta informação assim. Por exemplo, na segunda linha da tabela fica diferente, então qual é a chamada no PHP que gera este valor?

Comment: Reformulei a pergunta

Comment: Por favor, me ajudem, to 2 dias com essa fórmula bendita ai. ^^_

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas

Comment: @DanielOmine não coloquei os códigos aqui porque "só eu entendo", eu até queria colocar, mas ele está meio bagunçado, coloquei no Google Drive também para não deixar minha pergunta muito extensa, para que quem quiser resolver possa executar no seu computador, entende? Mas obrigado, nunca tinha lido essas dicas. E o que achou da minha pergunta?

Comment: A pergunta está ok. O problema é que depende de um link terceiro o arquivo excel. Se esse link deixar de existir a pergunta perde o sentido. Por isso torna-se fora de escopo ou não clara o suficiente. E pior ainda se  possui algo que só você entende, conforme comentou. Talvez melhor perguntar num forum pois aqui o formato deve ser mais objetivo.

Comment: @DanielOmine entendi, de qualquer forma consegui chegar numa solução através do link que o MarceloBoni passou abaixo, ai eu coloquei uma resposta como solução, mas obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Dada a seguinte formula para se calcular juros compostos dado um valor inicial e um valor de investimento mensal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/26187

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
function valorFuturo($valorInicial, $taxaJuros, $periodo, $investimentoMensal)
{
    $jurosComposto = (1 + $taxaJuros) ** $periodo;
    $v1 = $valorInicial * $jurosComposto;
    $v2 = $investimentoMensal * ( ( $jurosComposto - 1 ) / $taxaJuros ) * ( 1 + $taxaJuros );
    return number_format($v1 + $v2, 2, ",", ".");
}

echo "R$ ".valorFuturo(2500, .00333333, 60, 100)."<br/>";
```

Por falta de exemplo, eu testei usando os mesmos valores:

```
valorInicial: 2500
taxaJuros: 0.04 anual que mensal vira 0.003333333
periodo: 5 anos ou 6 meses
investimentoMensal: 100
```

O valor bateu com o esperado: R$ 9704,49

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/OleO2A)

Detalhe **!importante!**

Para cálculos de valores muito grandes de cunho financeiro, opte sempre por usar o máximo possivel de casas apos a virgula, veja no seu exemplo usa: `0.54/100` que é igual a 0.0054000000000

Se você estender as casas apos a virgula no excel vera que o valor real utilizado de taxa para o calculo é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pense em valores grandes, assim como fez

```
100.000 * 0.0054 = 540
100.000 * 0.00543169 = 543.169
```

Uma diferença de +3 unidades, e quanto maior forem os valores, maior sera a divergência no valor final.

Comment: No seu deu certinho MarceloBoni?

Comment: To tentando criar um exemplo funcional, seria legal dar um exemplo de valores iniciais (input), e resultado esperado (output)

Comment: Cara a segunda resposta desse link que você me passou funcionou pra mim, vou editar a pergunta pra vocês verem. http://money.stackexchange.com/a/16517

Comment: Fico feliz que funcionou, pode criar uma nova resposta do jeito que fez, pelo jeito ficou diferente dessa resposta :)

Comment: Cara só mais uma coisa, como eu poderia fazer com que a minha taxa ficasse mais precisa, porque a taxa não vai ser fixa, será alterada com o `input` do usuário.

Answer (score 0):

## Solução


https://money.stackexchange.com/a/16517
É feito o valor futuro do pagamento, e depois o valor futuro passado(linha anterior, ou iterador anterior).

Valor futuro do pagamento

```
<ul>
<li>$pmt: Pagamento</li>
<li>$i: Juros</li>
<li>$n: Número de períodos</li>
</ul>
Valor futuro da última linha(valor futuro passado, linha anterior).
<ul>
<li>$vl: Valor futuro</li>
<li>$i: Juros</li>
<li>$n: Número de períodos</li>
</ul>
```

Agora é feita a soma dessas duas fórmulas. Vocês podem ver no código o funcionamento.

```
function valorFuturo($vl, $i, $n, $pmt, $iterator)
{
  if($iterator > 0):
  $first  = $GLOBALS['ul_vf'] * (1+$i)**$n;
  $second = $GLOBALS['ul_pgto'] * ((1+$i)**$n-1)/$i;
  $vf     = $first + $second;

  $GLOBALS['ul_vf']   = $vf;
  $GLOBALS['ul_pgto'] = $pmt;
 else:
  $vf                 = $vl;
  $GLOBALS['ul_vf']   = $vf;
  $GLOBALS['ul_pgto'] = $pmt;
 endif;
 return $vf;
}




$vlr_imovel   = 144000; 
$vlr_aluguel  = 400.00; 
$vlr_entrada  = 43200.00; 
$vlr_encargos = 500.00;
$mes = 360;

$taxa = (0.54/100);
$se_for_investir  = $vlr_encargos + $vlr_entrada;

for($i = 0; $i <= $mes; $i++):

  $juros_no_finan    = (($vlr_imovel - $vlr_entrada) - ((($vlr_imovel - $vlr_entrada)/$mes)*$i))*0.007;

  $amortizacao      = ($vlr_imovel - $vlr_entrada)/$mes;

  $vlr_total        = $amortizacao + $juros_no_finan;

  //VALOR FUTURO -------------------------
  // Como: FV = PV x ( 1 + i ) ^ n
  $n            = 1; 
  $pgto         = $vlr_total - $vlr_aluguel;
  $vlr_presente = $vlr_entrada + $vlr_encargos;
  $tipo         = 0;
  $taxa2        = 0.54316901573592300/100;

  $vf           = valorFuturo($vlr_presente, $taxa2, $n, $pgto, $i);
  //VALOR FUTURO -------------------------


  $sac['G'][] = $se_for_investir;
  $sac['H'][] = $juros_no_finan;
  $sac['I'][] = $amortizacao;
  $sac['J'][] = $vlr_total;


  $sac['K']['pgto'][] = $pgto;
  $sac['K']['vf'][]   = $vf;

endfor;
```